# Unable to login to Stack Exchange by using Google credentials after adding others

Tags: support, login

Initially I logged in using my Google account. Later, I also connected my Facebook account to my Stack Exchange account. Now I am unable to login to the site by using any credentials.

[image: Login Error]
I checked the console, and it throws an error message like this:

[image: Console Error - loaded over HTTPS but requested an insecure script]

Comment: Is there anything logged in your browser console?

Comment: ya I updated the question with console log @JAL

Answer (score 2):

It seems something is doing a MITM attack. It can be your corporate firewall or proxy which wants to know what you are typing in, but it can be something else too.

If you are within a company network, and the `10.221.50.7` machine is a corporate firewall or proxy, you know you have to knock on the system administrator's door. Else it might be a plugin or your ISP fiddling with your request.

I would suggest to try another browser, another machine and another network to check who is at fault here.